# How do you rotate qt embedded application?

Tags: qt, qtembedded

I tried qt-gfx-transformed but it doesnt happen to work . Its showing error that transformed driver not found. Is there any way to rotate Qt application ?

Comment: Question should show the actual error message (for search engines etc), and preferably a sufficiently complete code snippet which generates the error.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21899586/476681)